# Fields of Special Characters SharePoint List is not created in React project

Tags: sharepoint-online, react

I have created below function in separate library to create list and its 3 fields in the react project, however, its working with normal character SharePoint list but not with special characters list e.g Employee`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-,.<>?;:"[]{}|. System created special character SharePoint list but don't added three fields and throwing error:

`isHttpRequestError: true`

response:

```
Response {type: "default", url: "", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}

status: 400

statusText: "Bad Request"

message: "Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] Bad Request ::> 
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
"message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"web/lists/getByTitle('~!@\" is not valid."}}}"
```

---

```
public async CreateList(listTitle: string, siteURL: string, listDescription: string, fields: any[], isHidden: boolean = true) {

return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {

try {

let _web = new Web(encodeURI(siteURL));

// let _listName = this.utilityService.DecodeString(this.utilityService.decodeSpecialCharacters(listTitle));

var createListAddResult: ListAddResult = await _web.lists.add(listTitle, listDescription, 100, false, { 'Hidden': false });

this.getRollUpField(_web,listTitle);

if (createListAddResult.list != null) {

let listfieldsaddBatch = _web.createBatch();

//add fields to list

fields.map(field => {

if (field.FieldTypeKind == FieldTypes.Text) {

createListAddResult.list.fields.inBatch(listfieldsaddBatch).addText(field.title, 255);

}

if (field.FieldTypeKind == FieldTypes.Note) {

createListAddResult.list.fields.inBatch(listfieldsaddBatch).addMultilineText(field.title, 100, false, false, false, false);

}

if (field.FieldTypeKind == FieldTypes.Boolean) {

createListAddResult.list.fields.inBatch(listfieldsaddBatch).addBoolean(field.title);

}

});

await listfieldsaddBatch.execute();

let listfieldsinViewBatch = _web.createBatch();

fields.map(field => {

createListAddResult.list.defaultView.fields.inBatch(listfieldsinViewBatch).add(field.title)

});

await listfieldsinViewBatch.execute();

}

resolve(createListAddResult)

} catch (ex) {

console.log(ex);

reject(false);

}

});

}
```

Comment: It's a SharePoint standard to not use special characters anywhere in List/column/folder names. What is the issue?

Comment: Its client requirement, the function is written in separate library, and when its called in the project, its throwing error " Bad Request ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"